# Как реализовать возможность задавать произвольную функцию для программы?

Tags: c++

Друзья, добрый день! Встала такая задача: есть .cpp файл, в котором программируется алгоритм минимизации функции. Есть файл .cpp, в котором программируется сама функция. В программе минимизации нужно предусмотреть возможность изменять файл с функцией, чтобы можно было задавать разные функции. И вот теперь есть вопрос: как это лучше сделать? Каждый раз из программы с алгоритмом перекомпилировать программу с функцией? Если да, то как это проще сделать? Или есть способ легче?

Answer (score 3):

Тут все зависит от того, зачем и для чего это делается.

Если это лабораторная работа, то тут возможно достаточно добавить несколько разных функций и дать пользователю выбрать одну из них. А если ещё какие-то коэффициенты вводить, то скорее всего работа будет сделана отлично.

Если же это курсовая, то наверно стоит написать свой парсер арифметических выражений и дать пользователю возможность ввести функцию. Тут можно либо по этому же сайту поискать готовые варианты, либо реализовать [алгоритм сортировочной станции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)  и готово. (подсказка 1 - в украинской статье есть готовый код на с++. подсказка 2 - что бы не заморачиваться с разделением на токены, можно на первом этапе принять то, что пользователь сам будет пробелом разделять - то есть, `12 + 32 * x` и все сильно-сильно упроститься).

минусы у такого способа - на нормальную реализацию наверно нужно будет потратить неделю-две (что бы отловить всякие косяки) и код будет вычисляться не насколько быстро (думаю, в раз 100-1000 медленнее).

Плюсы - явно работа будет хорошо выполнена, будет куча знаний.

Если же писать лень (понимаю), можно взять готовый скриптовый язык. Например, питон (ну и выражения нужно будет писать на питоне) или Lua (это чуть ли не стандарт для встраиваемого скриптового языка) - [вот прям пример для Вас](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156572/evaluating-mathematical-expressions-using-lua).

Правда этим движкам нужны дополнительные dll, что может не подойти. Поэтому, можно использовать [Chai script](https://chaiscript.com/) - синтаксис чем то похож на си, но для работы с ним нужно только подключить один заголовочный файл. Как по мне - отличное решение даже для лабораторной работы.

Как бы делал я. Первое - спросить того, кто поставил задачу. Потом оценить свое время. Потом посмотреть на lua или chai script. Если это все не подойдет, открыть книгу дракона и делать свое. Может когда то получиться новый матлаб/октава.

Comment: Вот проблема как раз в том, что преподаватель предлагает просто менять файл с функцией. Почему-то объяснить человеку, что это не будет работать, так как это не Python, программа уже скомпилирована и ей как-то плевать на изменения исходников, я не смог. Вариант менять заголовочный файл с функцией и просто каждый раз заново компилировать программу не устраивает. Парсер писать - отдельная тема для курсовой. Вот я уже и думал вызывать gcc, перекомпилировать программу с функцией и т.д. Но, видимо, такой себе вариант. Спасибо, ответ хороший, но пока подожду, мб кто-то подскажет ещё что-нибудь

Comment: если хочется вызывать gcc - тогда видимо нужно функцию заворачивать в dll/so. И саму программу не нужно  будет перекомпилировать. Тогда лучше спросить преподавателя, как именно это все должно выглядеть. Хотя есть подозрение, что если приложить make/cmake файл, то вполне может быть. Хотя есть ещё такая штука https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584714/is-there-an-interpreter-for-c

Comment: @ВадимЕрмаков C++ - это действительно не питон, С++ является компилируемым языком и вполне естественно, что после любых изменений в программе ее надо пересобирать. Если у вас не было задачи реализовывать модификацию функций во время исполнения программы, то никакие вышеупомянутые самописные парсеры, готовые скриптовые движки или плагины не нужны. Просто пересобирайте программу. Из вопроса не ясно почему это вызывает затруднения. ¿Нажать кнопку "Запустить" в IDE - куда уж проще?

Comment: @user7860670 в вопросе написано, что предполагается изменение функции во время работы. И в комментарии выше я писал, что просто изменить функцию и пересобрать программу - не подходит

Comment: @ВадимЕрмаков В вопросе нет ни слова про изменение функции во время работы.